# Android Studio 4.1 keep showing plug in incompatible error even if that plugin was uninstalled

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, android-studio-4.1

I have updated Android Studio to version 4.1 (stable, macOS), then after I open the program it said:

`Plugin Error: Plugin "Android WiFi ADB" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).`

I uninstalled that plugin and restart the IDE normally, but it still shows the same error every time I open the IDE even after the plugin was already uninstalled! Why does it do that? Does anyone know how to fix this (without reinstalling the entire program)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I fixed it! Look like the uninstall button in the plugin GUI screen is just for decoration purpose only, the plugin is still in the `/Users/your_username/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins`. After removing the plugin folder manually everything is back to normal.

Comment: This solution works for MacOS. For Windows 10, GAYTH_BACCARI's solution is correct and for Linux, tsubus' solution should work.

Comment: there is no folder of such plugin

Comment: @user924 In mac, you can click `command + shift + .` in `your_username` folder to show `Library` folder. Then you can navigate as @chornerman answer.

Comment: Or you can just navigate through finder by only navigate to `finder` -> `go` -> `go to folder` and then simply paste this`/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/` you didn't find it because your android studio might have different version.

Answer (score 29):

### Windows 10

Go to path `%APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins` and remove manually undesired plugins folders and/or `.jar` files.

Comment: there is no folder/jar of such plugin

Answer (score 10):

### Linux

I had the same issue, removing the unsupported plugins in the the config folder fixed it (you can also remove the entire configuration folder, a new one will be re-created).

For linux, the new configuration path is:

`~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

There is also other non-configuration folders at the following paths:

`~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

`~/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

Answer (score 4):

### macOS

On Mac OS the path is different. Make your life easy and simply run this command in the Terminal after closing Android Studio:

```sh
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins/AndroidWiFiADB
```

Now it's gone.

Answer (score 3):

**For windows users**

```
go to below path and delete desired plugins.
```

> C:\Users*username*\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

Answer (score 1):

## Linux, JetBrains Toolbox:

Check `~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio`

On my machine I went to `~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/202.7486908.plugins` - I saw the plugin folders there and deleted them. Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

just noticed on my mac that Android Studio 4.0 vs 4.1 are in different sub directories
extra /Google path in 4.1

```
Android Studio 4.0
/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio4.0/plugins
Android Studio 4.1
/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins/
```

The plugin complained about "Activity Stack View" is in 4.1 plugins folder

```
Plugin Error: Plugin "Activity Stack View" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).
```

I closed AS and moved folder out of plugins and restarted and error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

#### **Linux, Android Studio**

Deleting incompatible plugin folders in this path worked for me:

*/home/Your_Name/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio<version>*

In case of multiple version folders delete plugin folder corresponding to your version. For me the version was 2020.3 and so the folder being AndroidStudio2020.3.

Answer (score 0):

For another plugin such as `Android ADB WiFi` or `ADB Wifi` I tried to install them but it does not work after removing plugin folder. In my case, I solved it by simply installing another plugin which named `ADB Wi-Fi`.

[image]